# Count until zero

Tags: android, count, app-inventor

I am beginner and trying to write some calculations with **App Inventor 2**.

I am trying to write a code to calculate Net present value.
The formula of **NPV = - investment + CF/(1+i)power up by years** of investment, which means if years of investment are > 1 the second part of formula will repeat until it reached the number of years.

I successfully code the formula for one year that works correct, but have problem with the "repeating" the second part powered by number of years.

I tried to declare years as variable to use it as powering number but think something is wrong with it.

In my opinion I need to split the powering number somewhere to memory and then increase it by 1 until the required number. However have no clue how to do it.

Can anyone help?

[Screenshot of the blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB9g8.png)

[image]

Comment: see also http://www.thecalculator.co/finance/NPV-Calculator-284.html is the cashflow for each year always the same in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the calculation from the [NPB Calculator](http://www.thecalculator.co/finance/NPV-Calculator-284.html), 
[image]

this is converted into blocks the following 
[image]

Note: for a better clarity and to avoid such long calculation blocks as in your screenshot, I used *External Inputs* instead of *Inline Inputs*, which is the default. You can switch that from the context menu after doing a right mouse click onto one of the calculation blocks.

**EDIT**: screenshot updated for changing cashflows using a list.
See also
[How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj and
 
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

Comment: It will help me to understand deeply the problem. Now just need to understand the procedur to genereate more fields for cashflow. But let me one more question...in this case it looks like the cashflow is always the same but it is usualy changing. So how does this work if cashflow is diferent for each year? Going to try it.

Comment: well, actually that was my question, see my comment above... in this case you could use a list as `cashFlow` parameter in the procedure..